# Is there a problem book similar to Polya & Szego's classic in the field of real analysis

Tags: reference-request

I'm going to learn real analysis, and I'm using the textbook written by Elias E. Stein(the 3rd in his series). When studing complex analysis, I find that Polya & Szego's book "Problems and Theorems in Analysis I/II" is very useful. So is there any book which consists of problems that is similar to Polya & Szego's?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 'Problems in Mathematical Analysis', written by Kaczor and Nowak. There are four parts of it, but in libgen, three parts are available. I couldn't find the fourth part anywhere. These books are really awesome, loaded with beautiful problems. You can go for it.